# Can I use Django 1.1 with django-search-lucene for full-text searching, and if so, what resources/links/docs can I reference to get it up and running?

Tags: python, django, django-search-lucene

A little background:

- I want to use [Django Search with Lucene](http://code.google.com/p/django-search-lucene/)
- I have Django 1.1 w/ Python 2.5 installed
- MySQL 5.1 is being used
- My local machine is running Windows Vista x64, but we will deploy to [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux)
- Yes, I wish that right about now I was running Linux.

Comment: If you're going to deploy on Linux, then you really, *really* want to get a linux server (hosted or something in the closet). And you want to do this now, as opposed to a week before you are ready to deploy. Really.

Comment: Or even just install Red Hat on your dev machine - via vmware or virtualbox if nothing else.

Comment: I gotta say Pete and Daniel: those are both excellent suggestions, but other people our team are using Windows, and while I could hold them down and force them to install linux, I'm afraid I'm not in a position to impose that requirement. I'll suggest it, and hopefully, everyone will agree your suggestions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [Apache SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which is built on top of Lucene. The primary advantage is that it exposes an easy to use API, and can return a native Python object. Here is an example of how to call it from Python:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({        
    "rows": "100",       
    "fl": "id,name,score,address,city,state,zip",        
    "wt": "python",        
    "q": "+name:Foo +city:Boston"
})        

request = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request("http://locahost:8983/solr/select", params))
response = ast.literal_eval(request.read())
request.close()            
return response["docs"]
```

Comment: Second the recommendation for Solr - there's even a Django project, Haystack, which provides integration with Django models.

Comment: Thanks! I can't use Solr because our technology stack due to reasons unknown can't support Java.

Comment: Well, Solr's what we ended up going with anyway! Thanks!